# find $\max \left\{ \operatorname{rank}((A+B)^2) : A,B \in \mathbb R^{2n,2n} \wedge \operatorname{rank} A + \operatorname{rank} B \le n \right\}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

how to find:
$\max \left\{  \operatorname{rank}((A+B)^2) : A,B \in \mathbb R^{2n,2n} \wedge  \operatorname{rank} A +  \operatorname{rank} B \le n  \right\}$
I assume that there is needed to prove some additional theorems. One of them I think that I got:

$$ \operatorname{rank} A^2 \le  \operatorname{rank} A$$
Take $x \in \ker A$ 
then $Ax=0$

Ok, now let's multiplicate from the left side:
$$ A^2x=A\cdot 0 = 0 $$
so $$\ker A \subset \ker A^2$$
and the result follows.
But I don't know how to deal with sum of $A,B$ :(

$$ $$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\def\col{\mathrm{col}} \col(A)$ denote the column space of $A$, then we have $\def\rank{\mathrm{rank}} \rank(A) =\dim\col A$, and
$$\col(A+B) \ \subseteq\ \col A+\col B$$
so we have $\rank(A+B)^2\le\rank(A+B) \le\rank(A)+\rank(B)\le n$. 
Then we have to find particular $A,B$ that satisfy the conditions and $\rank(A+B)^2 =n$. 
(For simplicity, we can even take $B=0$.)